# installing logstash plugins on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, logstash

Wondering if anyone has had any luck running logstash on Windows 10. I can get the simple stdin input and stdout outputs to work, but I can't install any additional plugins. For example, running `.\logstash-plugin.bat install logstash-input-heroku` yields this output:

> Validating logstash-input-heroku Installing logstash-input-heroku
>   Error Bundler::InstallError, retrying 1/10 An error occurred while
>   installing net-ssh (4.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure
>   that `gem install net-ssh -v '4.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
>   WARNING: SSLSocket#session= is not supported Error
>   Bundler::InstallError, retrying 2/10 An error occurred while
>   installing net-ssh (4.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue. Make sure
>   that `gem install net-ssh -v '4.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
>   WARNING: SSLSocket#session= is not supported

(etc.)

I don't see windows 10 in the [logstash support matrix](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#show_os) so I'm guessing it's not intended to work. Perhaps on the linux subsystem for windows? Has anyone tried that? Doesn't look like java8 runs on it.

Comment: Could be [helpful](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-heroku/issues/8) since the issue is similar.

Comment: @Darth_Vader actually I saw that issue but ignored it because it seemed totally ubuntu related. But I tried it anyway just for kicks and it worked! (At least the installation of two plugins claims to have succeeded. Will now see if the whole elk stack actually works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well installation seems to have now succeeded. Thanks @Darth_Vader for the suggestion. Here's the source [github issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-heroku/issues/8) that I referred to. The issue was resolved after updating the Gemfile (in logstash root folder) and changing the net-ssh and rest-client library versions:

```
# This is a Logstash generated Gemfile.
# If you modify this file manually all comments and formatting will be lost.

source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "net-ssh", "2.9.0"
gem "rest-client", "1.7.2"
gem "logstash-core", :path => "./logstash-core"
(etc...)
```